# Remote acsess to mac pc via iphone using iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using Ios 4.0

I want to build a project throw which we can remote access other i phone through one.Is it possible in any cases, its totally idea in dreams i don't know whether it is visible or not.

I haven't s

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are applications that allow mac/windows desktop sharing from an iphone/ipad (example RemotePC, Splashtop). And there are applications which allow you to access the iPhone screen from a desktop (Veency VNC). Hence accessing iPhone from another also should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=GameKit) for connecting iOS devices